# Substituting into equations

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation

If I evaluate `D[f[g[x]],{x,5}]`, I'll get a result containing derivatives of f and g, [explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula). But suppose that I have explicit formulae for the derivatives $g^{n}(x)$, for $n=1,2,\ldots$. How can I substitute these into my result, so that my result doesn't contain $g$ (or its derivatives), except for terms of the form $f^{n}(g(x))$? (Without copying and pasting manually.)

I've tried `Solve` and `Reduce`, but it doesn't actually substitute the function, and `Replace` doesn't work on this type of problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Define the known explicit formulae for the derivatives $g^{(n)}(x)$:

```
dg[1, x_] = x^2;
dg[2, x_] = x^77;
dg[3, x_] = Cos[x];
dg[4, x_] = Sin[x];
dg[5, x_] = -2;
```

Evaluate something and substitute, remembering that the [full form](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of a derivative is given in terms of the [`Derivative`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative.html) head:

```
D[f[g[x]], {x, 5}] /. Derivative[n_][g][x_] :> dg[n, x]

(*    -2*f'[g[x]] + 10*x^77*Cos[x]*f''[g[x]] +
      5*x^2*Sin[x]*f''[g[x]] + 15*x^156*f'''[g[x]] +
      10*x^4*Cos[x]*f'''[g[x]] + 10*x^83*f''''[g[x]] +
      x^10*f'''''[g[x]]                                   *)
```

Comment: This looks just like what I was after. Thank you so much.